# How do I iterate through a list of Strings to change the last letter of each word toUpperCase?

Tags: java, string, arraylist, bluej

This is for homework. I can't seem to return the correct code when my method gets executed. I'm not sure if my for loop is iterating properly or if i'm supposed to use the enhanced for loop. This is my code:

```
/**
 * Replaces the words in the string so that every last character is upper case
 */
public void lastToUpperCase() 
{        
    for(int i=0;i>list.size();i++)
    {            
       String chopped = list.get(i);           
       String chopped1 = chopped.substring(chopped.length()-1,chopped.length());
       String screwed1 = chopped.substring(0,chopped.length()-1);
       String chopped2 = chopped1.toUpperCase();            
       String frankenstein = screwed1 + chopped2;
       System.out.print(frankenstein);          
    }         
}
```

This is what is supposed to be printed:

```
[PeteR, PipeR, pickeD, A, pecK, oF, pickleD, peppers.]
```

Comment: `for(int i=0;i>list.size();i++)` is wrong, and you will need to replace the value in the `List` if you want the `List` to recognise your changes

Answer (score 1):

I would start with a [`for-each` loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) and use a `StringBuilder` (for [`setCharAt(int, char)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#setCharAt%28int,%20char%29)) and something like

```
for (String str : list) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);
    sb.setCharAt(sb.length() - 1, Character.toUpperCase(//
            sb.charAt(sb.length() - 1)));
    System.out.print(sb);
}
```

The issue with

```
for(int i=0;i>list.size();i++)
```

is that `i` is not `>list.size()` so your loop isn't entered.

```
for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
```

Comment: Assuming that my only instance variable is : private ArrayList <String> list; What would I put for the object: Character.toUpperCase() because as you wrote it I get a compiler error: no suitable method found for toUpperCase()

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on others' comments about the `for`: The second expression is treated like a "while" condition; that is, the loop keeps going *while* the expression is true.  As soon as the expression becomes false, the loop terminates, and the program goes to the statement after the loop.  The way you wrote this (note that it's easier to read with extra spaces, instead of all jammed together):

```
for (int i = 0; i > list.size(); i++)
```

`i` starts out as 0.  But then `0 > list.size()` is `false`, so it exits the loop immediately--that is, it never executes the list body even once.

Comment: Oops! Thanks for catching that ajb! I mean to use the < operator.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```
/**
 * Replaces the words in the string so that every last character is upper case
 */
public void lastToUpperCase() 
{
    for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++)
    {            
        String chopped = list.get(i);           
        String screwed = chopped.substring(chopped.length()-1,chopped.length());
        String frankenstein = screwed.toUpperCase();
        String von = list.set(i, chopped.substring(0, chopped.length()-1) + frankenstein);
    }
}
```